# doctest fails with no unified diff shown

Tags: python, pytest, docstring

I am trying to update tensorflow_addons doctest and I am getting the following error.

> Differences (unified diff with -expected +actual):

with no difference shown.
below is the code

```
>>> y_true = tf.constant([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
... dtype=tf.int32)
>>> y_pred = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 1]],
... dtype=tf.int32)
>>> metric = tfa.metrics.MultiLabelConfusionMatrix(num_classes=3)
>>> metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
>>> result = metric(y_true, y_pred)
>>> result.numpy()
array([[[2., 0.],
        [0., 2.]],
<BLANKLINE>
       [[2., 0.],
        [0., 2.]],
<BLANKLINE>
       [[0., 2.],
        [2., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

I am attaching a highlighted code also. so to let you know that there are no trailing spaces.

[highlighted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iEPo.png)

and the command that is being used to test is below

> pytest -v -n auto --durations=25 --doctest-modules /path/to/pyfile.

The test is failing when I get the output from result.numpy(). Attaching a pr where it is failing [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/2144)

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] that reproduces the error? The doctest runs fine when I copy it from your question.

Comment: @hoefling. I have attached a pr. the doctest works fine if I test it using python -m doctest -v example.py. It fails only when I use pytest(local installation) and in pr

Comment: It looks like a `pytest` issue to me. `pytest` uses a custom doctest runner which doesn't handle blank lines correctly here -- either use plain `doctest` to run the doctests, or remove `<BLANKLINE>`s, or disable blank line checking completely via `doctest: -DONT_ACCEPT_BLANKLINE` flag.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the ```pytest``` configuration file. The ```doctest``` option flag had a ```DONT_ACCEPT_BLANKLINE``` flag set. So, I used ```#doctest: -DONT_ACCEPT_BLANKLINE``` for the failing result.numpy() and it cleared the test, thanks